# Static Height Custom Cell ListView

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having some trouble working out the static height (35) on a custom cell row. I keep getting an overlapped list with a defined height when I try to bring down the return height below from 120 to 35.

```
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 120;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the return type of that function is a CGFloat, not an int.

Comment: Is this a custom cell? If so what do you have inside it?

Comment: @rdelmar there are 5 labels, organized by 3 on the left and 2 on the right. The custom cell height in the xib is 35.

Comment: Are these 3 labels side by side, or stacked vertically? I don't see any reason you shouldn't be able to set the height to 35 unless there's something in the cell that wants to be bigger than that.

Comment: Got it, thanks! The background picture height was bigger than the cell height and was added through coding. Background picture size has been changed and all is good. Thanks for the help.